# Warning: imagepng(): Filename cannot be empty in qrimage.php

Tags: php, qr-code

My code is

```
include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$reg_id.'<', '', 'H', '10', 2);
QRcode::png('><', '', 'H', '10', 2);
die();
```

when I running my qurcode for png its work fine on my local server but in live server its display wanrning Warning: imagepng(): Filename cannot be empty in file_path/qrimage.php on line 43

Comment: make sure the file has the correct permissions and it can be read by the apache/httpd

Comment: Please check if your gd library loaded in your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the [function signature](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/docs/html/class_q_rcode.html#a1b90c0989105afa06b6e1c718a454fb5) is:

```
QRcode::png($text, $outfile=false, $level=QR_ECLEVEL_L, $size=3, $margin=4, $saveandprint=false)
```

For `$outfile`, you're supplying an *empty string* `''`. This is likely where the error stems from. Since the default value for `$outfile` is `false`, if you do not want to supply an outfile parameter, you should probably use `false` instead:

```
QRcode::png('><', false, 'H', '10', 2);
```

Comment: I passed already false. In your code it seems that you are passing through variable and I directly passed both are same. This code running successfully in my local server.